# In InnoDB, Why rows which are not in index range are getting locked?

Tags: mysql, innodb

consider the below query..

> select * from Employee where ID>0 and ID <5.

- here ID is the primary key,Employee is an Innodb table, transaction isolation is read committed and there are no rows in the table for the range ID>0 and ID<5.

  I thought the above query will only lock the id ranges between 0 and 5 but id 6(for id 6 data is there in table) is also getting locked which is preventing other transactions to update.

while doing explain , the row count it is showing as 1.

```
explain select * from Employee where (ID>0 and ID<5);
+----+-------------+----------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table    | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+----------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | Employee | range | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 8       | NULL |    1 | Using where |
+----+-------------+----------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+-------------+
```

But there is no actual rows in system.

```
select * from Employee where (ID>0 and ID<5);
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

show engine innodb status output:

```
---TRANSACTION B3D2D, ACTIVE 2109 sec
2 lock struct(s), heap size 376, 1 row lock(s)
MySQL thread id 894932, OS thread handle 0x7f53263e0700, query id 4140397 localhost root
```

INNODB_LOCKS table output:

```
    +----------------+-------------+-----------+-----------+----------------------+------------+------------+-----------+----------+-----------+
| lock_id        | lock_trx_id | lock_mode | lock_type | lock_table           | lock_index | lock_space | lock_page | lock_rec | lock_data |
+----------------+-------------+-----------+-----------+----------------------+------------+------------+-----------+----------+-----------+
| B42F4:1822:3:7 | B42F4       | X         | RECORD    | `jbossdb`.`Employee` | `PRIMARY`  |       1822 |         3 |        7 | 6         |
| B42ED:1822:3:7 | B42ED       | X         | RECORD    | `jbossdb`.`Employee` | `PRIMARY`  |       1822 |         3 |        7 | 6         |
+----------------+-------------+-----------+-----------+----------------------+------------+------------+-----------+----------+-----------+
```

INNODB_LOCK_WAITS output:

```
+-------------------+-------------------+-----------------+------------------+
| requesting_trx_id | requested_lock_id | blocking_trx_id | blocking_lock_id |
+-------------------+-------------------+-----------------+------------------+
| B42F4             | B42F4:1822:3:7    | B42ED           | B42ED:1822:3:7   |
+-------------------+-------------------+-----------------+------------------+
```

PS : Am using mysql version 5.5

Any guess?

Comment: Did you try to `Explain` the query?

Comment: It's called gap locking. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-locking.html

Comment: Please provide the output of (1) SELECT * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.INNODB_LOCKS and (2) SELECT * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.INNODB_LOCK_WAITS

Comment: I have added innodb_locks and Innodb_lock_waits output. Please check.

Comment: Thanks for the details. This confirms the contention happen on ID=6 (see lock_data). Is "select * from Employee where ID>0 and ID <5" the only statement in a the transaction, or are there other statements executed before ? Also, for the blocking transaction, what queries is it executing ?

Comment: Yes we have 2 transaction. we have delete query running in both the transaction. delete from Employee where ID>0 and ID<5.(in both transaction). Because of this, contention is happen on ID 6.

Comment: @MarcAlff Do you have any clue about this? Thanks!

Comment: Some observations so far: (1) when trying to reproduce in 5.5.56, EXPLAIN SELECT gave "Using where; Using index" while you have only "Using where". (2) the row lock is 'X', which means an exclusive lock, and seem to be taken by the DELETE statement, not the SELECT. (3) If two transaction both do a delete, the contention seems legitimate. Not sure what the application attempts to to here. (4) I suspect an "off by one row" lock to happen : the sql layer needs to delete rows 1-5, so does a fetch by primary key (ID=1), then fetch_next in a loop, until ID>5. The last row 6 is fetched=locked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting with MySQL 8.0.1, you can actually see all the data locks taken in innodb, they are instrumented by the performance schema:

```
SELECT * from performance_schema.data_locks;
```

See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/data-locks-table.html

Possibly related, from the 8.0.1 release notes:

InnoDB: A gap lock was taken unnecessarily during foreign key validation while using the READ COMMITTED isolation level. (Bug #25082593)

So, even when a GAP lock is not supposed to be used by MySQL, it is still worth checking what locks are actually used, using the performance schema.

Comment: @user2641906 There should be no gap lock, yes. Do you have PK / FK on this by any chance ?

Comment: The column ID is PK and there is no FK in the table.